# vestal_versions GEM error -Cannot define multiple 'included' blocks?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I am trying to use the GEM "vestal_versions" for version control in my Ruby on Rails application,
ruby 2.1.2p95 (2014-05-08 revision 45877)and Rails 4.1.1 with postgresql as back end.I followed the steps mentioned in 
[enter link description here](https://github.com/laserlemon/vestal_versions/tree/master)
but am getting some error while doing data base operations.`ActiveSupport::Concern::MultipleIncludedBlocks: Cannot define multiple 'included' blocks for a Concern`
.how to rectify this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That repository needs updating. The pull request is [here with the fix](https://github.com/laserlemon/vestal_versions/pull/107). You can find a working version at https://github.com/altagem/vestal_versions/tree/rails-4_1

Add this line of code to your gemfile and you should be good to go.

```
gem 'vestal_versions', :github => 'altagem/vestal_versions', branch: 'rails-4_1'
```